# Testing Android Mobile Application using Loadrunner 11.5 gives error

Tags: testing, mobile, performance-testing, loadrunner, android-testing

I am using Loadrunner 11.5 evaluation copy on Windows 7-64 bit.

I am trying to test Android based mobile application (built on Android 2.2) using the Protocol option 'Mobile Application – HTTP/HTML' which is provided by Loadrunner 11.5.

I have created a AVD, named 'Test_1' with Target Name: Android 2.2, Platform: 2.2, API Level 8 and CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi).

I am performing the following steps:

1. Open VuGen.
2. File --> New script and solution -->  Protocol: Mobile Application – HTTP/HTML
3. Recording Options: Port Mapping --> Capture Level --> Socket Level Data (By default only one option and non-editable)
4. Record --> Recording Type --> Record Emulator – Record Script using a mobile device emulator
5. Emulator to record: F:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\AVD_Manager.exe
6. Command Line: `-avd Test_1 -netspeed full -netdelay none` where Test_1 is the 'AVD name' which is displayed when the AVD Manager is opened.
7. Working Directory: F:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2
8. Record into action: Action
9. Finish

I am getting 3 different results at different times:

**RESULT 1:** 
The recording starts and I am getting pop-up named `Critical Error` displaying `Unable to determine AUT's bit capacity` (As per my knowledge, AUT means 'Application Under Test'.) alongwith a command window with title as 'F:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\AVD_Manager.exe'
Later on I have to close both the Pop-ups.

**RESULT 2:**
The recording starts and I am getting pop-up named `Critical Error` displaying `Unable to determine AUT's bit capacity` (As per my knowledge, AUT means 'Application Under Test'.) alongwith a command window with title as 'F:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\AVD_Manager.exe'
Then when I press OK on the pop-up, the AVD Manager opens. Then I select the device name i.e. Test_1 and click on start.
The Emulator starts and then I can record.
But this happened only ONCE.

**RESULT 3:**
The recording starts and I am getting pop-up named emulator-arm.exe has stopped working.

Please let me know where am I going wrong or do I need to put some more inputs?

Do I need to provide \tools\emulator.exe in the 5th step above?

A quick reply would be nice as my evaluation copy will expire on 26th Aug'12.

Answer (score 0):

Read the installation guide on 32 bit vs 64 bit.   Also, as you are in the midst of a product evaluation please contact your VAR or Vendor Sales Systems' Engineer.   These individuals are charged with ensuring that your proof of concept is successful so you will move forward with your purchase.   This will be your fastest path to a resolution.

These same individuals in sales can extend your license for a short window if all of your proof of concept questions have not been satisfied to move forward with your purchase.

Comment: James, Thanks for your answer. Saw it on the very same day but replying now!
I searched on Google, some are saying that VuGen doesn't work on 64 bit windows (that guy had written that he had talked with HP guys)
One of them said that it IS POSSIBLE to use VuGen on 64 bit.

Fortunately, even after getting pop-up of `Unable to determine AUT's bit capacity` , i was able to start the emulator and recorded the script, generated load upto 25 Vusers.

But I am `getting blank graph in Avg. Response time!`

Is there any other way to find the Avg response time?

Comment: James, I read about the `RESPONSE TIME` issue on sqaforums replied by you.
I have an error of HTTP Status-Code=500[MsgId: MERR-26612],i still used that script.
Is that the reason?
Now i ran the test with `Continue on errors = OFF`
I got the `following results`
Transaction Response Time = 0.000 for Max, min, avg, std, last of Vuser_init_transaction & Vuser_end_transaction; 
Transactions/sec (passed) = 0.042(Avg) for Vuser_init_transaction and 0.040(Avg), 1.250 (last) for Vuser_init_transaction;
Transactions/sec (failed/stopped) = 1.250 (last);
Total Transactions/sec (passed) = 1.250 (last)

Comment: As you are evaluating the tool given the question you have I can only assume you have not yet had the opportunity to attend training.   Leverage your VAr or Vendor Systems' Engineer for your questions.   This is why they are involved in your sale and purchase process.   As a moderator for a half a dozen forums on LoadRunner I have been asked specifically by Mercury and HP to refer organizations such as yours who are evaluating LoadRunner prior to purchase to HP or your VAR in order to ensure the fastest possible turnaround on answers impacting your evaluation of the product.

Comment: James, Thanks a lot for all your quick help.
I got the error solved in the script.
Lets see whether my company buys the tool or not.

Comment: @Vikram Patil, I am following the same steps you mentioned and i am getting Result 2 mentioned in your question. What did you do to fix it ?